# What interface or method should my class implement to print what I want in Console.WriteLine?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, console.writeline

I have an object of class F.  I want to output the contents of the object using Console.WriteLine for quick and dirty status updates like this:

Console.WriteLine(objectF);

This prints out only the name of the class to the console:

```
F
```

I want to overload this somehow so that I can instead print out some useful information about the object and its properties.

I have a workaround already:  To overload the ToString method in my class and then call:
Console.WriteLine(objectF.ToString());

But I would rather have the simpler syntax.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Console.WriteLine(objectF)

Should work, if you overloaded `ToString`. When the framework needs to convert an object to a string representation, it invokes `ToString`.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    // replace the line below with your code
    return base.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should override ToString() though in some situations you may just find the following code useful:

```
public static class ObjectUtility
{
    public static string ToDebug(this object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return "<null>";

        var type = obj.GetType();
        var props = type.GetProperties();

        var sb = new StringBuilder(props.Length * 20 + type.Name.Length);
        sb.Append(type.Name);
        sb.Append("\r\n");

        foreach (var property in props)
        {
            if (!property.CanRead)
                continue;
            // AppendFormat defeats the point
            sb.Append(property.Name);
            sb.Append(": ");
            sb.Append(property.GetValue(obj, null));
            sb.Append("\r\n");
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Usage is to simply include the namespace containing ObjectUtility and then...

```
var f = new F();
Console.WriteLine(f.ToDebug());
```

The reflection usage above isn't very good for high performance code so don't use it in a production scenario where high performance is desired.

Answer (score 1):

I would continue to use ToString().  That's its purpose for existing.  Also, unless you have a format string, you can just write:

```
Console.WriteLine(objectF)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of my problem.  I had neglected to define my implementation of ToString() as an **override**.  The correct syntax is:

```
public override string ToString()
{
   ///Do stuff...
   return string;
}
```

Thanks to the posters below who put me on the right track